# Consulta SQL para pegar todos os registros do mês passado porém até o dia atual

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Bom dia,
Preciso saber um % de variação de registros de tarefas do mês passado, para os registros de tarefas feitos esse mês. Para isso eu preciso comparar com o dia atual, por exemplo.

**Caso hoje fosse 15/10/2015**
Preciso contar quantas tarefas foram abertas entre **01/09/2015 até 15/09/2015** lembrando que isso precisa ser feito de forma automática, ou seja, o dia 15 citado no exemplo, tem que ser pego a data da maquina. 
Cheguei nisso apenas:

```
select *
from Solicitacao 
where UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655 and 
DATEPART(m, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Essa query retorna as tarefas abertas no mês passado INTEIRO, como preciso da variação, tenho que comparar do inicio até o dia atual do mês passado.

**OBS:** Estou usando SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, somente do mês passado é exatamente o que tu fez, porém não precisa subtrair um ano do dia atual. O que tu está solicitando pra query é:
Quero todas as solicitaçãoes que tiveram a data de fechamento(SolDataFechamento) 
no mês passado

*( AND DATEPART(m, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1,GETDATE())) )*

e no ano passado

*DATEPART(yyyy, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))*

Basta tirar isso da sentença:

```
SELECT *
FROM Solicitacao  
WHERE
UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655
AND DATEPART(m, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(YEAR, SolDataFechamento) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
```

Porém se tu desejar todos os dados do mês passado até o dia de hoje exatamente, ou seja, dados desde o dia 01/09 até o dia 30/09 (caso hoje), basta adicionar mais uma condição pra ela, que é:

> *AND DATEPART(DAY, SolDataFechamento) <= DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())*

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Cara, obrigado também, funcionou EXATAMENTE!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, veja o exemplo abaixo como vc pode esta fazendo

```
    declare @data datetime = (select getdate())

    declare @ano int , @mes int
    set @mes = (select month(@data)) 
    set @ano = (select year(@data))


    DECLARE @dataInicio DATE
    DECLARE @dataFinal DATE

    DECLARE @date1 DATETIME =  REPLACE(@ano, CHAR(0), '') + '-01-' +REPLACE(@mes - 1, CHAR(0), '') -- @mes - 1 mes anterior ao atual
    DECLARE @date2 DATETIME =   REPLACE(@ano, CHAR(0), '') + '-01-' +REPLACE(@mes, CHAR(0), '') 
    set @dataInicio =  (SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @date1), 0))
    set @dataFinal = (SELECT DATEADD(ms ,-3 ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @date2), 0)))

    select @dataInicio, @dataFinal

---
and SolDataFechamento between @dataInicio and @dataFinal
```

Comment: Cara!
Exatamente isso, deu certinho, obrigado!

Comment: Cara uma observação, eu fui testar aqui e coloquei -2 no mês pra testar com o mês de agosto, e ele puxou o dia 31/08, nesse caso teria que puxar até dia 29...

Comment: @ViníciusFernandes fiz uma correção na data final ... estava vindo o mês anterior.

Comment: @ViníciusFernandes tinha um + 1 na ultima linha , veja agora.

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada se é isso que você precisa:

```
WHERE NOME_DO_SEU_TABLE > GETDATE() -30
```

Com o comando GETDATE() você consegue pegar a data atual e colocar um range de datas a frente do mesmo, assim como eu fiz acima, selecionando todos os valores que tiverem na sua tabela com -30 dias da data atual.

Comment: Quase isso, porém dessa forma ele vai pegar 30 dias retroativos, por exemplo:

Se hoje for dia 15/10/2015 ele vai pegar desde o dia 15/09/2015
Eu precisaria que ele pegasse do dia 01/09/2015 a (dia_atual)/09/2015 no caso 15/09/2015

Comment: Aaaa entendi.. vou dar uma pesquisada aqui.

Comment: A resposta do Marconcilio Souza funcionou!

Comment: Maravilha! Eu testei aqui, realmente uma boa solução.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @hoje datetime
set @hoje = '20151015'

declare @dataend datetime
set @dataend = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @hoje)


declare @datainit datetime
set @datainit = DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@dataend) - 1), @dataend)

select @datainit, @dataend
```