# Como pegar os registros dos últimos 15 dias - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Possuo uma tabela chamada `Entrega` onde ficam armazenadas todas as entregas feitas com suas respectivas datas, como posso trazer apenas as entregas dos últimos 15 dias? Fazendo dessa forma consigo trazer as entregas a partir do dia 10 de outubro, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM public.entrega where data >= '2017-10-10' order by data desc;
```

Porém como posso determinar os últimos 15 dias para que fique algo mais dinâmico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após adaptar o que foi encontrado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95509/consulta-sql-para-pegar-todos-os-registros-do-m%C3%AAs-passado-por%C3%A9m-at%C3%A9-o-dia-atual) minha query ficou assim e consegui o que precisava:

```
SELECT * FROM public.entrega where data >= CURRENT_DATE - 15 order by data desc;
```

Comment: Lembrando que essa consulta, além de retornar registros de 15 dias atrás, retorna também registros de amanhã até o final dos tempos.

Comment: @Lacobus, mas por que ela retorna os registros de amanhã até o infinito? Sempre que executo essa query ela esta me trazendo o resultado correto

Comment: O que eu quero dizer, é que o intervalo é *infinito*  se `data >= CURRENT_DATE - 15`. Se houver algum registro que apresenta data **futura** (em relação a data corrente) no campo `data` esse também será retornado. Para recuperar registros somente dos `últimos 15 dias` seria necessário algo como: `data >= CURRENT_DATE - 15 AND data <= CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: Por exemplo se por um acaso houver um registro com data `20/10/2017` hoje no banco ele seria retornado no caso? Mesmo utilizando o `CURRENT_DATE`?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Se você estiver aplicando apenas a condição `data >= CURRENT_DATE - 15` datas *futuras* serão retornadas. Se hoje for `16/10/2017` todas os registros de `20/10/2017` seriam retornados também!

Answer (score 2):

Recupera os registros contidos na tabela `public.entrega` que possuem o campo `data` preenchido com datas dos ultimos 15 dias, sem considerar datas futuras.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    public.entrega
WHERE
    data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - '15 days'::interval AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY
    data DESC;
```